# Include <linux/spinlock.h> linker

Tags: linux, header, linker

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
DECLARE_TASKLET (test_tasklet, test_func, (unsigned long) &test_data);
```

from what `ld` does know which `library` or `object-file` must be linked with our source file?

Answer (score 1):

> from what ld does know which library or object-file must be linked with our source file?

It doesn't. *You* must specify required libraries and object files to the linker.

You are possibly thinking of Microsoft `#pragma comment(lib, ...)`, which doesn't exist in any other compiler I know of.